# WPF - error: [xxx] "does not contain a definition for [zzz] and no extension method [zzz] could be found

Tags: c#, wpf, compilation, compiler-errors

I get an error while compiling:

'SimulatorUi.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'UserCtrlSimulator' and no extension method 'UserCtrlSimulator' accepting a first argument of type 'SimulatorUi.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I got this error while compiling a user control and its owning window in the same project.

Why ?

Comment: It sounds like you've got another class named `MainWindow` in the namespace scope, you probably need to fully qualify the `MainWindow` reference you're using.

Comment: @Michael, thanks a lots, a friend told me something similar. I already found my bug and added the solution in order to help anybody with the same bug. I did add question and answer at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the naming of the userControl in its owning Window. I named as:

```
Name="UserCtrlSimulator"
```

instead of:

```
x:Name="UserCtrlSimulator"
```

You can find the bug and a more useful error message by removing the reference of that badly named object (remove any reference to the object named without the "x:").

I can't tell the exact reason why it is like this ??? But my solution works fine.

Hope it can help anybody because I lost a lots of time with this weird bug.

Comment: @Rohit, thanks for the corrections :-) ! It is better like that !